# download jars and wars from artifactory and copy to a specific folder using gradle

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I am new to gradle and artifactory and trying to download jars and wars from artifactory and copy to a specific folder using gradle. How can I do this?

My artifactory repository is a generic one where in I am uploading all the jars and wars. From here I want to download them and copy them to a folder.

This is what I got from the artifactory. I replaced the repoKey with my-repo where the jar and war files are located.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4+"
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'my-repo-upload'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
       } 
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'my-repot'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true            
        }
    }
}
```